# How to hide the colorscale in plotly subplots?

Tags: r, plotly

I am very new to (plotting in) R and I stumbled across this example on the plotly.com pages

```
library(plotly)

fig1 <- plot_ly(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6), type = 'bar', 
                marker = list(color = c(4,5,6), coloraxis="coloraxis"))

fig2 <- plot_ly(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,5), type = 'bar', 
                marker = list(color = c(2,3,5), coloraxis="coloraxis"))

fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2, shareY = TRUE)
fig <- fig %>%layout(showlegend = FALSE, coloraxis=list(colorscale='RdBu'),
                     plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6', 
         xaxis = list( 
           zerolinecolor = '#ffff', 
           zerolinewidth = 2, 
           gridcolor = 'ffff'), 
         yaxis = list( 
           zerolinecolor = '#ffff', 
           zerolinewidth = 2, 
           gridcolor = 'ffff'))
fig
```

And I wanted to know what I would have to add in order to print the subplot without the color bar on the right hand side?

Thanks in advance!

I tried with hide_colorbar(fig) after the code above, but that didn´t change anything

Comment: Based on how you've plotted this, you're probably best off using this `fig %>% htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x) {$('g.cbcoloraxis.colorbar').remove();}")` It's a non-native Plotly method, but the other methods of removing it will be a lot more work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! While this seems to work at first glance, as soon as I maximize the graph window, the color bar reappears somehow.. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: I wish I would have figured this out before I originally commented. I thought I tried this already, but I must not have. When you decare the `coloraxis` in `layout`, change it to `coloraxis = list(colorscale = 'RdBu', showscale = F)`